# How to compare numbers from a stream if the same number repeats

Tags: c++, fstream

I am trying to get the same numbers that repeat to be writen to a different stream
the function `void lygink`

```
void lygink (int s,int e,int n,int a , int m,info K[],int &sk)
{
    a=0;
    for (int i=1; i<=m; i++)
    {
        if(K[i].j==K[i].l) ;
        else {
        e=K[i].j;
        s=K[i].j;
        if (e==s)  {
        cout <<  e<< endl;

        }
        }
    }
}
```

The whole code is as follows:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;
struct info
{
    int jurg,lin,k;

};
void skaityk(int &n,int &m,int lin, int jurg, info K[])
{
    {
        ifstream fd ;
        fd.open ("U2duom.txt");
        fd >> n >> m;
        for (int i=1; i<=n; i++)
        {
            fd>>K[i].lin ;
            cout<<fixed<<setprecision(2)<<" " <<K[i].lin;
        }
        cout << " "<< endl;
        for (int i=1; i<=m; i++)
        {
            fd>>K[i].jurg ;
            cout<<fixed<<setprecision(2)<<" " <<K[i].jurg;
        }
        cout << " "<< endl;
        fd.close();
    }
}
void lygink (int s,int e,int n,int a , int m,info K[],int &k)
{
    a=0;
    for (int i=1; i<=m; i++)
    {
        if(K[i].jurg==K[i].lin) ;
        else {
        e=K[i].jurg;
        s=K[i].jurg;
        if (e==s)  {
        cout <<  e<< endl;

        }
        }
    }
}
int main()
{
    int n,e,m,a,lin,jurg,s,k;
    s=22;
    info K[500];
    skaityk(n, m,lin, jurg, K);
    lygink(s,e,n,a,m,K,k);
    int i;
    return 0;
}
```

and the file is

```
8 14
5 6 6 9 14 25 8 26
5 20 6 7 13 7 9 10 12 20 15 16 21 5
```

It should only give me 7 and 20 but it gives all that are not the same and I can't figure out how to extract those numbers I need to eliminate the numbers that do not repeat or somehow get the numbers that repeat

Comment: In `lygink()`, `e` and `s` are set to the same value. Maybe that could be it? Note that it's extremely hard to read your code; try using more descriptive names for variables instead of single letters.

Comment: This code can't be read at all. You should consider changing the names to give the meaning they are used for to enable the one trying to help you to read the code easily.

Comment: Use std::sort to sort the array and std::adjacent_find to find duplicates. A good programmer uses the available tools and doesn't reinvent the wheel every time.

Comment: `5 20 6 7 13 7 9 10 12 20 15 16 21 5`, "it should only give me 7 and 20" and "same numbers that repeat more than once" is a tad confusing.  I think you want "numbers that repeats" or "numbers that occur more than once", not "repeat more than once".  In the test set 7 repeats once, not more than once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use std::sort to sort the array and std::adjacent_find to find duplicates. A good programmer uses the available tools and doesn't reinvent the wheel every time.

```
std::unordered_set<int> unique(std::vector v) {
    std::sort(std::begin(v), std::end(v));
    auto it = std::adjacent_find(std::begin(v), std::end(v));
    std::unordered_set<int> ret;
    while (it != std::end(v)) {
        ret.insert(*it);
        std::advance(it, 2);
        it = std::adjacent_find(it, std::end(v));
    }
    return ret;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I would do the job somewhat differently. As a first attempt at things, I'd probably do something on this general order:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <set>
#include <sstream>

int main() { 

    std::istringstream input(R"(
        8 14
        5 6 6 9 14 25 8 26
        5 20 6 7 13 7 9 10 12 20 15 16 21 5 
    )");

    std::set<int> numbers;

    int n;

    while (input >> n)
         if (!numbers.insert(n).second)
            std::cout << n << "\n";
}
```

This produces more output than just 7 and 20, but hand inspection seems to confirm that everything it says is a duplicate actually is.

Comment: I need to eliminate the nubers that not repeat or somehow get the numbers that repeat

Comment: @Laurynas: What this prints out are numbers that are repeated.